# gridx with JSONRest - Creating and querying

Tags: dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid, dojo

Just wondering if anyone can help me with this issue. I have a Gridx connected to a JSONRest store. It works but when the grid starts up it seems to make a call to my server. I dont want this to happen. The server call takes two parameters and i only want this to be called when i query the store.

my code:

```
var restStore = new
    dojo.store.JsonRest({target: "search"});       

grid = new Grid({
          id: 'grid',
          cacheClass: Cache,
          store: restStore,
          autoHeight:true,
          pageSize: 10,

          modules: [
                    Pagination,  
                    PaginationBar  
                ],          

                paginationBarSizes: [10, 25, 50],
                paginationBarVisibleSteppers: 4,
                paginationBarGotoButton: false,
                paginationBarDescription: true,

          structure: [
            {id: "description", field: 'description', width: '100%',
                formatter: formatter,  

            }
          ]
    });
```

query to the store which works

```
    grid.model.clearCache();

    grid.store.query({term : term, category : category}).then(function(results){
    });
```

Also if i have the gridx inside another widget, it gets called again when the other widget starts up.

Any body any ideas how i get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Gridx takes a 'query' parameter in it's initialization arguments, which sets initial query for the store. gridx queries the store on startup to populate itself for the first time. just specify

```
.......
query: {term : term, category : category},
......
```

in gridx initialization and it will perform that query for you on startup to populate your grid